# JacksonNode iterator, get key value

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I am converting a variable of type "User class" populated with values to a JsonNode as follows:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
val node = mapper.valueToTree<JsonNode>(userData)
```

I need to iteratively loop through every element of that node, and get its key and value, example:
"name": John,
"lastname": H
etc.
So I have the iterator through the json node:

```
val iterator: Iterator<JsonNode> = node.iterator()
```

But when I do iterator.next(), I directly get John value, without the key. And I need to get both the key and the value.
How I can access the key in an iterator of type JsonNode?
Anything I'm doing wrong, or is there a better way to iterate through those properties?

Answer (score 2):

`JsonNode`'s [`iterator()` method](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#iterator())

> Same as calling `elements()`; implemented so that convenience "for-each"
> loop can be used for looping over elements of JSON Array constructs.

For `ObjectNode`, [`elements()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#elements()) is implemented to return field names

> Method for accessing all value nodes of this Node, iff this node is a
> JSON Array or Object node. **In case of Object node, field names (keys)
> are not included, only values.** For other types of nodes, returns empty
> iterator.

This is not what you want. You want something like [`fields()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#fields())

> Method to use for accessing all fields (with both names and values) of this JSON Object.

which returns an `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>>`, where the `Entry` key is the name and the `JsonNode` is the value.

You have to cast your `node` to `ObjectNode` to be able to call `fields` (assuming it is an `ObjectNode`).

There are other, more aptly-named, methods like [`fieldNames()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#fieldNames()) that give you all the key names, which you can then use with [`get(String)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#get(java.lang.String)) to retrieve values.